# How to create "unsafe" environment for JavaScript XSS testing

Tags: javascript, security, xss, owasp

I am learning about XSS security and how to prevent it. To do that I would like to create voulnerable code and then see how adding security measures would fix it.

I created an html file that accepts parameters and should execute alert when called like this:

```
http://localhost/index.html?name=<script>alert('XSS attack!')</script>
```

but I am unable to succeed - it looks like browsers are already doing some security checks for me. What would be the best way how to create a working environment where I can execute such code and then fix this security hole with CSP?

Comment: Where is the code which tries to execute that param?

Comment: Something would have to insert the value of that `name` parameter _into_ the HTML code that your server returns, when requesting this URL - did you do anything, to make that happen ...? (Seeing how the file suffix is `.html`, I am guessing this is probably just a static file.)

Comment: So, inside html file is JavaScript code that appends name parameters value. I tried to do it with innerHTML and with insertAdjacentHTML but can not get to execute

Comment: You may want to read [OWASP Cross Site Scripting](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) which provides explanations, practical advice, and example [test scripts](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/stable/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/01-Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_Site_Scripting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script` tags don't get executed when you add them to an existing DOM as HTML text (for instance, by assigning to `innerHTML` or using `insertAdjacentHTML`). But if you stored that "name" server-side, then included it in the server-side rendering of the page (both without adequate sanitization), it would run and the Evil Code™ would execute. That kind of vulnerability is sadly common.

But `onxyz` attributes don't even require that kind of server round-trip: `?name=<img src="-" onError="evilCode();">Joe` That would trigger the code even when added via `innerHTML` and such:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
        "Your name is: " + name;
});
```

```html
<label>
    Name:
    <input id="name" type="text" value="<img src=&quot;-&quot; onError=&quot;alert('XSS attack!')&quot;>Joe">
</label>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Save">
<div id="display"></div>
```